# Calculate average delivery time laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a e-commerce application. All delivered orders have a column "updated_at". I can with this column calculate average delivery time total delivered orders?

I have count all orders and column updated_at.
What I need do, that calculate average time?

My code:

```
$deliveryTime = Order::where('status', '8')->count(); //get A count delivered orders..
```

Comment: As I think, it will need more complex SQL query and it will need using `created_at` field to get delivery time for each order, then calculate average.

Comment: problematically ;((

Comment: `SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,created_at,closed))) AS a FROM orders WHERE status = 8`

Comment: @Jadasdas where does the order created date is stored?

Comment: @ab_in in column `created_at`

Comment: then you should calculate the date diff b/w the created_at and updated_at to find the delivery time and find its average.

Comment: You can publish your answer with example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OP's question and comment :

**Average delivery time = average of ( date difference of order creation date and order_delivery_date)**

> order creation date field = `created_at` order delivery date field =
>   `updated_at`

```
$averageTime = Order::select(\DB::raw("DATEDIFF(updated_at, created_at)AS day_diff"))->where('status', '8')->get()->avg('day_diff');
```

If it required to round off the value you can use `round($averageTime);`

Comment: I get: 66.285714285714. 66 days - this average time of delivery? :)

Comment: In db I have dates, how I can verify?

Comment: reduce the size by additional constraints for testing. if you want to verify manually calculate the date difference and find average and verify it with the code result.

Comment: My code is tested in my conditions and it was success.[assuming you have `timestamp` data type for both `created_at` and `updatd_at`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167467/discussion-between-ab-in-and-jadasdas).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. It wil return you the average of the orders where status is 8

```
$deliveryTime = Order::where('state', '=', '8')->select(DB::raw('AVG(created_at) as order_average'))->get();
```

Comment: But how I can get average delivery time? I need get, example:  average delivery time: 15 days

Comment: Depends on your database, but look into the `DATEDIFF(date1, date2)` sql function paired with `AVG(column)`.